# Refresh specific div after AJAX UPDATER with prototype js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prototypejs

I want to update a specific div with `id=message-board` after an action takes place, and everything works fine and it is executed properly. The problem is that I want to refresh the div with the new results. In my case the div is closed after complete and I need to refresh my page in order to have what I except. Thank you. Following is the code sample.

> ```
>   remove:function(mid){           
>         var l_sParams = 'message_id='+mid;
>         var l_sURL = '/ajax/caller/delete_message_board';           
>         new Ajax.Updater('message-board',l_sURL,{parameters: l_sParams, method:'POST',
>                          onComplete:function(a_oRequest){
>                             // maybe here is requested code to refresh the div              
>                          }.bind(this)
>         });
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you need to use `Ajax.Request` instead of `Ajax.Updater`. Ajax.Updater is designed to simply update the content of a container with the response of an Ajax call. If you want to do more with an ajax request use Ajax.Request like this

```
remove:function(mid){           
    var l_sParams = 'message_id='+mid;
    var l_sURL = '/ajax/caller/delete_message_board';           
    new Ajax.Request(l_sURL,{parameters: l_sParams, method:'POST',
                onComplete:function(a_oRequest){
                     $('message-board').update(a_oRequest.responseText);
                     // Or if the results are JSON
                     $('message-board').update(a_oRequest.responseJSON.message);
                     $('message-board').show(); //if the div is hidden
                     // maybe here is requested code to refresh the div              
                 }.bind(this)
    });
}
```